# \lccode`\'=39 breaks hyphenation rules

Tags: hyphenation

I tried to use

```
\lccode`\'=39
```

in preamble in order to correctly hyphenate words with apostrophe, but it produced an infrequent but annoying side effect: some words left the single last letter (no matter whether vowel or consonant) hyphenated.

In 2019 what should be the right approach to preserve correct hyphenation and allow for the words with apostrophe to be hyphenated as well?

Comment: Can you provide a small but complete example of code that shows what you mean.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: In 2019, using babel ( https://ctan.org/pkg/babel ) or polyglossia ( https://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia ) should be the right approach to preserve correct hyphenation and allow for the words with apostrophe to be hyphenated.